# Small N analysis for a field experiment question, and rare events logit

Tags: experiment-design, small-sample, zero-inflation, rare-events

so, I am running a "Field" experiment, meaning, people in a real life situation are subject to certain treatment, and I am trying to measure the effect of said treatment.

In this case its an online donation campaign, so donations. I have two mailing lists, approx 2000 people in each arm. as things are advancing I am getting few donations, many factors might be playing to this. So at the moment one arm has approx 30 donations, the other, approx 17. I feel confident that some analysis (which include both donors (1s) and non donors (0s) ) will be fine, specifically maybe using rare events logistic regression... to check the probability of donating for example. I worry more about analysis with the continuous variable for donation (so amount of $ given ) given my current amount of donors. Any ideas what analysis might be good for such a case (if lets say, numbers stay the same, 30 vs 18, total donations 420 dollars vs 220, means 16 vs 11)

Any ideas what might be advisable?

Comment: I think the search term you are looking for for your second question is zero-inflated Poisson/negative binomial regression. We have a relevant tag [tag:zero-inflated]

Comment: Indeed! I just added it, lets see if I get a hit or two, thanks a lot! (Given that I have a donor or two that were very generous, there is a slight concern about dispersion)

Comment: If you go down that route you need negative binomial of you have over-dispersion.

Comment: hmm the thing is that my outcome variable of interest is continuous right? $$$, so Im not sure I can follow that path.. unless I categorize the outcomes  (( Edit, wait I might be gettig mixed up : Zero-inflated Poisson uses a mixture model for the 0s, and the Poisson GLM for the "non-zero part"

Comment: You could view it as a count since I assume people give a whole number of dollars. I suspect there might be a lot of clumping at multiples of 10 and to a lesser extent five so you could consider categorising it and using ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: For a different perspective -- one that argues against fitting a logistic regression to predict "donate or not" -- see the section [Bad COP](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/07-Beyond-Confounders.html#bad-cop) of the [Causal Inference for The Brave and True](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/landing-page.html) book. COP stands for "Conditional on Positives". The gist is that after removing the non donors, the two groups of doners might no longer be balanced even if the experiment was randomized.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good read and yes, it seems that dividing up the sample into donors and non donors might lead me to some problems.. So, overall a rare event logit where all responses are included will work well, but I will only be assessing there the probailities of donating, I guess I will have to analyse then 0s and donations (as continuous dollar values) to check effects on donation sizes, and avoid splitting the sample up